# Why don't absolute classpaths work when starting clojure repl?

Tags: clojure, compilation, read-eval-print-loop

A problem has traped me for quite a while when I'm exploring Clojure. I try to generate a class by invoking the `compile` function in REPL on a Clojure script as below:

```
(ns mylib.DirLister (:gen-class))
(defn -listDir [this path]
     (->> path java.io.File. .listFiles (map #(.getName %))))
```

I saved this script to *e:/temp/clj/src/mylib/DirLister.clj*. The following session goes well when I specify the **relative paths** for the `-cp` option, i.e., classes are successfully generated in the classes path:

```
e:\temp\clj>java -cp .\src;.\classes;d:/tools/clojure-1.4.0/clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (compile 'mylib.DirLister)
mylib.DirLister
user=>
```

But when I use **absolute paths**, there prompt a "No such file or directory" error:

```
e:\>java -cp e:/temp/clj/src;e:/temp/clj/classes;d:/tools/clojure-1.4.0/clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (compile 'mylib.DirLister)
CompilerException java.io.IOException: No such file or directory, compiling:(mylib/DirLister.clj:1)

user=>
```

How come ? I mean why the absolute paths don't work but the relative paths do.

I know I could go with leiningen. but since I'm studying Clojure, I want to understand the stuff underneath before adopting this full-featured tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer:

the `compile` function will always use the value of the built-in variable `*compile-path*` as the path of the output classes, which defaulted to "classes" under the current directory if you didn't set it otherwise. So the problem I came across is not really about relative or absolute path, it is about the current directory and the value of `*compile-path*` .

Refer to [ClojureDoc](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/compile) .

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you have a mixture of forward-slash and backward-slashes on the command line.  I'm not sure exactly what shell you are using and whether that could make a difference.  But, a path with e: in it would normally require a back-slash '\'.  Maybe this will help, or at least remove one potential source of problems?

Could you try to change the 2nd example to use

`e:\temp\clj\src;e:\temp\clj\classes;d:\tools\clojure-1.4.0\clojure-1.4.0.jar`

to see if that helps?

Comment: Thank you Roger. I'm using windows. I've tried both, but no luck.

Comment: Strange thing: If I quote the paths it will be ok. e.g.,`java -cp  "e:/temp/clj/src";"e:/temp/clj/classes";d:/tools/clojure-1.4.0/clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main`   Why ? Is it a stupid windows shell problem ?

Comment: I still don't know the answer to what is going on, but I can say that the error comes from not finding the classes directory.  Try seeing what the difference is with this snippet: (doseq [u (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader)))] (println u))